# Drop-down autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I want dropdown autocomplete matching letters to be bold, here is my code for dropdown autocomplete:

```
var states = {
  'Color': ['red', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', ],
  'Numbers': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
};

function match(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    clearDialog();
    for (var i = 0; i < states.color.length; i++) {

        if (states.color[i].toLowerCase().includes(str)) {
            jQuery('.dialog').append('<div>' + states.color[i] + '</div>');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think a simple CSS class combined with an addClass() would serve your purpose - maybe it could work even without jQuery addClass() method

Comment: @DavideVitali : Only the matching character needs to be capitalized. Right now the whole string would match the css. I guess you need to update your markup so that the matching characters are put in a separate tag, that you can select in your css.

Comment: i have an input with autocomplete dropdown , when i type any letters in input the dropdown auto-completes  words with that letters, so i just want the letters matching to be bold. see example with highlighting words mathing here: https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/#basic-usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you might want to perform a `<span>` tag insertion before appending the newly created div so that, creating a CSS class, you can set the bold font within, or even change its color or any other property later:

```
.dialog > div > .match {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Then, you can append this new `text` to your dialog

```
...append(‘<div>’ + text + ‘</div>’);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var states = {
        'Color': ['red', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'Dark Green', 'Light Grey'],
        'Numbers': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
    };

    $('input').on('keyup', function () {
        match($(this).val());
    });

    function match(str) {
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        $('.dialog').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < states.Color.length; i++) {
            if (states.Color[i].toLowerCase().includes(str)) {
                var mStart = states.Color[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(str);
                var mEnd = mStart + str.length;
                var text = states.Color[i].slice(0, mStart);
                text += '<span class="match">';
                text += states.Color[i].slice(mStart, mEnd);
                text += '</span>';
                text += states.Color[i].slice(mEnd);
                $('.dialog').append('<div>' + text + '</div>');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.dialog > div > .match {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<div class="dialog">
```

Comment: the thing is that it would make all word to be bold, but i need letters matching in  dropdown to be bold

Comment: Isn’t the ‘append’ function in your code appending to your dialog only the matching elements?

Comment: Oh okay, I got it now. You want the matching **substring** to be bold...

Comment: it appends words which have same letters typed in input , for example if i type "rk" it  will show "New York" an "Arkanzas" , so i want it to be like this "New Yo**rk**", "A**rk**anzas", matching letters to be bold.

Comment: @Tod I0ve added a **working** JSFiddle. It was the selector in the CSS that prevented the text from being bold, but there were also some errors in your code that needed to be fixed, like the name of the array `color` instead of `Color`

Comment: @Tod once again, I edited the snippet to reflect capital letters (I've added a couple colors in the array).

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible by using `<strong>` tag on append function.
To achieve this you need to split it into two parts of word 1).Non-matched part and 2). Matched part.

For matched part put string into `<strong>` tag and other simply append

for reference check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete) W3School Tryit Editor link of Autocomplete.

Helpful code:

```
b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
```

where `b = jQuery('.dialog').html()`

Comment: The ‘<strong>’ tag suggestion is a good one, as it goes out for simplicity without dealing with CSS classes and selectors, that on the other hand offers more flexibility. BTW, you need to split the string in **three** parts, because matching substring most likely are going to be in the middle of the word

Comment: @davideVitali thanks for change. I missed this middle matching case.

Comment: @Tod please update source with modification it will be helpful.

Comment: @asav sorry dont know how to do that