# Autocomplete middle of the text not only on start

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to implement a custom autocomplete list in middle of the text not just from the beginning?

Lets say, I have a custom autocomplete list like this.

```
['@Martin','@Josu','@Mikenko','@Buarandun','@Ravindran','Basix','#ItemNr']
```

When I type the following in the input, `'Hallo @M'`, it should list `['@Martin' ,'@Mikenko']`

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

Thank you.

Comment: Check this: [drop down autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222201/drop-down-autocomplete)

Comment: It is not middle on the text, only on start.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const searchInput = document.getElementById("search");
const output = document.getElementById("output");
const names = [
  "@Martin",
  "@Josu",
  "@Mikenko",
  "@Buarandun",
  "@Ravindran",
  "Basix",
  "#ItemNr"
];
searchInput.addEventListener("input", matchNames);

function matchNames(e) {
  const { value } = e.target;
  output.innerHTML = ""
  // start matching if '@' symbol found
  if (value.includes("@")) {
    const symbolIndex = value.indexOf("@"); // get the symbol index
    const matchValue = value.substring(symbolIndex); // start matching from symbol index
    const matchList = names.filter(
      name => name.toLowerCase().indexOf(matchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    );
    // output
    const html = matchList.map(name => {
      const Name = name
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(matchValue, `<strong>${matchValue}</strong>`)
      return `<span class="name">${Name}</span>`
    }).join("")
    // push data into output
    output.innerHTML = html
  }
}
```

```css
.name {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="names">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This part

```js
inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
var a, b, i, val = this.value;
```

convert to

```js
inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
var a, b, i, val = this.value;
val = val.split(' ').reverse()[0];   // Get last
```

This should get last word always

Answer (score 0):

you can apply condition based on characters length after which you want to start autocomplete. For example you can say

```
if(yourInput.length > 3 ) {
  //your rest autocomplete thing here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `search()` method. Read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp).

Change following

```
if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
```

to

```
if (val.toUpperCase().search(arr[i].toUpperCase()) != -1) {
```

Not tested, Hope this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change

```
var a, b, i, val = this.value.split("@");
/*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
closeAllLists();
if (!val || val.length < 2) { return false;}
val = val[val.length-1]
```

then

```
if(arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase())
```

to

```
if(arr[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
```

And change showing the list from

```
b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
```

to

```
b.innerHTML = arr[i].toLowerCase().replace(val.toLowerCase(), '<b>' + val.toLowerCase() + '</b>');
b.style.textTransform = "capitalize";
```

It will start to show autocomplete when you just typed '@' in your text.

Example [codepen](https://codepen.io/atiqul052/pen/qBdyVvQ)

Comment: I'm sorry, my question wasn't detailed enough. When I: "Hello Colom" it should list Colombia. Now it doesn't match.

Comment: In that case you need to mention which part of your text need to be start to autocomplete. Otherwise every time it will show autocomplete list when ever you start to writing. I just changed the [codepen](https://codepen.io/atiqul052/pen/qBdyVvQ). Please have a look.

Comment: Another simple change made to the [codepen](https://codepen.io/atiqul052/pen/qBdyVvQ). Now you just write '@' and it will start to show autocomplete where you want, like any other IM (skype, messenger etc)